# Could MySQL innoDB pages get fragmented inside hard disk? Or InnoDB prevents that from happening to speed up queries?

Tags: mysql, innodb

By pages i mean:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-page-structure.html

Could these 16KB MySQL pages get fragmented inside memory or disk? meaning if we take a disk image or memory image, could there be a chance that these 16KB pages be fragmented? Meaning if I take an Image of the MySQL folder, will the 16KB pages be in continuous blocks or some of them could get fragmented?

or MySQL implement them in a way that they don't get fragmented? if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a filesystem or operating system question than MySQL or InnoDB. InnoDB is writing to a file, and it is indeed possible that the filesystem fragments the writes to a single 16 KiB InnoDB page so that it is not contiguous on the physical disk. However, with modern servers and SSD storage, this basically happens 100% of the time anyway on the underlying media.

It is generally not a concern for me, at least.

Comment: Thanks for answer! So MySQL doesn't make sure that these 16KB pages get a  continuous blocks to speed up queries?  wouldn't that affect the performance a lot if they get fragmented? also why fragmentation doesnt happen with modern servers? do they always provide  continuous blocks?

Comment: On modern operating systems there is no actual way to ask for your data to not be fragmented, that allocation (and potential fragmentation) occurs at such a low level that it's not visible or controllable by an application such as MySQL.

Comment: sorry to bother again, but then do you have any thoughts on this paper? :  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287615000584 . They use page carving to recover data from databases like MySQL, but if these pages get fragmented then how this method gonna work? (they look for pages inside disk image, using an ID which is the same for all pages, then recover its content)

Comment: @OneAndOnly - Fragmentation on SSDs is _not_ a performance issue.  On HDDs, the seek time is where fragmentation costs time.

Answer (score 1):

(I already discussed disk a length in your similar question.  I'll address RAM here.)

Perhaps two decades ago, more than half the CPUs had moved to "virtual" addresses being distinct from "physical" addresses.  To achieve this, the hardware guys implemented a "translation" mechanism that mapped a 32-bit (or 64-bit) virtual address that the program uses into a physical address for accessing RAM.  This was done at a relatively low level in the hardware.  Along with the hardware came the handling of the exception when the physical address is swapped to disk or had not yet been allocated for the user program.

The manufacturers mostly settled on 4KB page size for the precision of the translation.  That is the bottom 12 bits (2^12=4K) are fed through the translation untouched; the top bits are mapped (via an on-chip lookup table, backed by an array in RAM), from virtual to physical.  This is done for every memory access (except maybe during booting).

With that mechanism, user programs can be *totally* oblivious of where the 4KB pages are in RAM, and also whether they are scattered or not.

Bottom line:  Forget about the memory image.  Fragmentation is really a non-issue.

On the other hand, swapping can be an issue.  I think that MySQL and InnoDB are designed with the assumption that everything in RAM stays in RAM.  Notice how they go to the effort to cache data blocks, index blocks, table definitions, etc.  So, do *not* tune MySQL such that the system needs to swap.